# tastypie and django test cases

Tags: python, django, http-post, tastypie

I am having some trouble with writing a unit test that checks my custom resource post attribute is working. I have managed to make it work with a simple manual jquery, but that isn't helpful for long term testing.

Suppose my test looks like this:

```
def testCollectionPost(self):
    """ Test Create Entry operation.
    """
    initialData = self.client.get(self.collectionUrl, format='json')
    jsonObject = json.loads(initialData.content)
    initialCount = jsonObject['meta']['total_count']

    dataToPost = {'id': initialCount + 1} # Real version contains other appropiate data
    response = self.client.post(self.collectionUrl, data=json.dumps(dataToPost), content_type='application/json')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
    responseGet = self.client.get(self.collectionUrl, format='json')
    jsonObject = json.loads(responseGet.content)
    self.assertEqual(jsonObject['meta']['total_count'], initialCount + 1)
```

This gives me back a 500 error, and I have been utterly unable to get back a real traceback.

Off my main page, I ran the following which worked fine:

```
dataToPost = {'id': 277} # Real version has more data, that matches the unit test.
pResp = $.ajax({ type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://nelsog2.blah.example.com/metrics/api/v1/system_info/',
    data: JSON.stringify(dataToPost),
    contentType: 'application/json'})
```

Anyone have an idea fo what the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems to have fixed itself. My guess is the request was being caught by a cache returning the 500 error, after I had already fixed the issue.